# Display different launch images for different iPhone devices using Launchscreen.Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have been searching for this since last two days but I didn't get the solution. I have searched a lot in the Stack overflow also. My requirement is I have to display different images for different iPhones. i.e for iPhone 5 assume 5.png, for iPhone 6 assume 6.png, for iPhone X assume x.png in the LaunchScreen.storyboard file. Any ideas/suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance for your time and effort

**Why I need is:** In the splash image I have 3 different set of images (top, bottom and Center images). Those images positions are changing from one iPhone device to another device. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: I initially thought this could be resolved by size class. But since you mentioned your iPhone5 and iPhone 6 can also have different images. My suggestion is to make a class to define your implementation for different cases I have.

Comment: You cannot; you are limited to autolayout constraints in your launch storyboard. You could have a simple launch storyboard that is replaced by a more complex initial scene from your main storyboard, where you can use code.

Comment: @TheNitram Custom code doesn't execute at the time of loading the LaunchScreen.storyboard :(

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for the reply

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Launch Images` in the `Assets.xcassets` instead of `LaunchScreen.storyboard`? You may provide completely different screens for every single device.

Comment: Launch Images in an Assets catalogue is deprecated as of iOS 13.  Apple says to use a Launch Screen storyboard, but the original question remains: how to specify a different image for each device size like we could in the assets catalogue?